# How to improve performance of custom function with manual vectorisation in R

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I have two data frames: df1 providing the coordinates of given symbols, and df2 providing start and end coordinates. I need to get the sequence of symbols between each start and end coordinate in df2.

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(POS = 1:10000000,
              REF = sample(c("A", "T", "G", "C"), 10000000, replace = T))

df2 <- data.frame(start = sample(1:5000000, 10, replace = T),
                 end = sample(5000001:10000000, 10, replace = T))
```

I have tried using a for loop:

```
system.time( {                
df2$seq <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(coords)){
  df2$seq[i] <- paste(ref$REF [ c( which(ref$POS == coords$start[i]) : which(ref$POS == coords$end[i]) ) ], collapse = "")
}
})
```

And using manual vectorisation:

```
mongoose <- function(from, to){
  string <- paste(
    ref$REF [ c( which(ref$POS == from) : which(ref$POS == to) ) ],
    collapse = "")
  return(string)
}

mongoose_vec <- Vectorize(mongoose, vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))

system.time({
  sequences <- mongoose_vec(from = df2$start, to = df2$end)
  })
```

However, both of these methods perform at similar speeds and are not sufficiently fast as the dataset I am applying them to is very large. Does anyone have any suggestions for how performance could be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorize will not significantly speed up your task as it just reduces overhead, but most of the computation is within the loop itself.

One approach you can take is to store `ref` as a  long string and use the `substr` function.

```
ref2 <- paste0(ref$REF, collapse="")
system.time({
sequences2 <- sapply(1:nrow(coords), function(i) {
  substr(ref2, coords$start[i], coords$end[i])
})
})

user  system elapsed 
  0.135   0.010   0.145
```

Your original code:

```
system.time({
  sequences <- mongoose_vec(from = coords$start, to = coords$end)
})

   user  system elapsed 
  7.914   0.534   8.461
```

The results are identical:

```
identical(sequences, sequences2) 
TRUE
```

PS: I assume `df1` is the `ref` and `df2` is the `coords`.